# Как задать расстояние между пикселями в border:dotted?

Tags: css

Допустим, есть такой класс:

```
.star{   
border:1px dotted #FFFFFF;  
}
```

В разных браузерах расстояние между точками бордера разное.  Как сделать, что бы между ними был 1 пиксель и не больше?

Comment: Никак в CSS, но можете сделать бэкграундом.

Comment: Однопиксельный dotted во всех современных браузерах одинаковый. Но если не нравится, то появился border-image, который можно настроить.

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего не "изобретать велосипед" а использовать

```
background:url('dоted.png') left bottom repeat-x;
```

тогда расстояние между `dots` будет именно таким каким было изначально заданно при отрисовки!

Comment: очень интересно, а как же быть если размер блока различен?

Comment: background-position:bottom;http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-position

Comment: @koza4ok, давно в курсе, очень давно. Отсюда вопрос - как вы так собираетесь обрисовать все 4 стороны? Если только перечислением фонов, но это CSS 3

Comment: да не похоже ты точно не в курсе! Если принципиально стоит задача одинакового отображения в большинстве браузерах, то самый простой способ использовать background, на подобие http://jsfiddle.net/J8QEa/1/ ,либо делать костыли на js которые будут нагружать систему и не будут работать в старых версиях IE,

Comment: @Cone, давно я такой разметки не видел )
вы и в правду считаете что это хороший метод решения, обернуть элемент в 3 div'a?

Comment: @Gedweb, если есть задача "любой ценой", а стандартных средств для решения нет, то и способ, предложенный @Cone, заслуживает внимания.

Comment: @Deonis, "любой ценой" - испытывал подобное. Но это явно не тот случай, человек как я понял учиться, если задаёт такой вопрос. А картинками можно сверстать всё, но делать этого не стоит